# css fixed and absolute problems

Tags: css, position

I have 3 elment in my page. They are outer, middle and inner.

html code:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">

      <div class="inner">
        inner suppose to stay at the bottom of the outer.
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
.middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 100px 0;
  position: static;
  background: green;
}
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height:100px;
  background: yellow;
  bottom: 0
}
```

I think inner should stay at the bottom of outer. However, I doesn't. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: inner is in the bottom of outer. Remove the `overflow:auto` and put a border to the outer `div` to see.

Comment: well, I need inner stay at the bottom of outer while I scroll outer.

Comment: Yes, I suppose what is you want but is not easy, I'm trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

Set your middle class to position relative.

```
.middle {
position: relative;
}
```

This fixes your problem, but unfortunately I can't give a good explanation why. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: well, I need inner stay at the bottom of outer while I scroll outer.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you want to be able to scroll over middle and always have inner at the bottom of outer.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="scrollableContainer">
        <div class="middle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        inner suppose to stay at the bottom of the outer.
    </div>
</div>

<style>

.outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    height: 400px;
}

.scrollableContainer {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.middle {
    border: dotted;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    padding: 100px 0;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    bottom: 0
}
</style>
```

Or if you wanted to have the inner always on the bottom of the middle then the solution from Frutis works but i have also no explanation. And you could put the inner outside the middle into the outer under the middle (what?)

like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        inner suppose to stay at the bottom of the outer.
    </div>
</div>
```

and make your inner relative.

Comment: which method do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this, the problem is the width of inner, can't use 100% because overlap the scrollbar. I set in 184px and works fine in my PC with Chrome and Firefox but maybe in others browser or SO is not the best value:

```css
.dummy {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.outer {
  max-width: 400px;
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: green;
}

.inner {
  width: 184px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="inner">
        inner suppose to stay at the bottom of the outer.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```